# simulate async with array and callback in javascript

Tags: javascript

if I had an array and a callback function, how do I get the results back asynchronously? here's what I've been trying

```js
const fakeAsync = (list = [], cb = '') => {
  let map = {};
  list.forEach((x) => {
    map[x] = cb(x)
  })

  return map;
}

const list = [
  'user1',
  'user2',
  'user3'
]

const cb = (name) => {
  setTimeout(function(){ return 'good ' + name }, 3000);
}

fakeAsync(list, cb)
```

it prints out

=> { user1: undefined, user2: undefined, user3: undefined }

I want it to be

=> { user1: 'good user1', user2: 'good user2', user3: 'good user3' }

Comment: I think you have that backwards, your code as shown wouldn't print out `user1:'good',...` as the return statement is inside the anonymous function not the `cb` function

Comment: Do you want to fire off a bunch of "callbacks" and collect the results of each of them into an array? Or do you want to invoke a single async function n times and populate an array of n elements with the results?

Comment: @PatrickEvans I guess I'm just trying to simulate an async call with the cb

Comment: @RayToal => { user1: 'good user1', user2: 'good user2', user3: 'good user3' }

Answer (score 0):

Calling `cb` will return nothing directly, so the `return` inside the `setTimeout` doesn't actually return anything to be put inside the `map` object.

You could use Promises to get it simulated like this:

```
const fakeAsync = (list = [], cb = ()=>{}) => {
    Promise.all( // Wait for all Promises to settle/resolve
        list.map((x) => { // Make an array of Promises from the list
            return new Promise((resolve) => { // Return Promise to be settled
                setTimeout(() => { // Simulated delay before resolving with a return value
                    return resolve(cb(x))
                }, 3000)
            })
        })
    ).then((map) => { // Get all returned values from the Promises
        console.log(map);
    });
}

const list = [
    'user1',
    'user2',
    'user3'
]

const cb = (name) => {
    return 'good ' + name; // The actual return value
}

fakeAsync(list, cb);
```

Some references/documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises

Comment: is there a way to do this without using Promise? I'm just trying to understand how to do things in js without having to use the newer features. a way to have a delay in the cb

Comment: You can use `setTimeout` to execute some code after a delay, but then you need the code that handles the return/result to also be inside that timeout (or be called then).

Comment: This kind of thing, where you have multiple callbacks, is _why_ promises were created. Before promises people would do things like create modules like async which had crazy functions like waterfall, serial, parallel, and so on. Sure, learn callbacks for simple things, and go study the inner workings of modules like async, and even learn how features like `promisify` work. Whether or not you master all that crazy stuff (and yeah it _is_ cool), you will and should use promises and async/await in your production code. It is more robust and a lot easier to understand.